# Map over list of dataframes

Tags: r, loops, purrr

I am trying to map over a list of data frames but I am doing something wrong.
I have multiple dataframes in my environment, my  objective is to replace all empty strings with NA values
what I am doing is the following:

```
# create a list of my dataframes
lst <- ls()
lst<- lst[sapply(lst, function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)))]
# second, map my function on all of my dataframes
map(lst, ~.x %>% mutate_if(is.character, list(~na_if(.,""))))
```

and I get the following error mesage `Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") :  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"`

I think I am doing something wrong with the indexing but I am not sure what it is.

If anyone could help (the output should be data frames) I would be extremely grateful

Comment: Can you show the `str(lst)`. Your code should work fine if the datasets are all data.frame

Comment: The OP is asking for why the error occurs and the dupe link doesn't serve that

Comment: Dear Arun, the str(lst) is a character vector of all the dataframe in the dataset
`chr [1:18] "audit1" "audit2" "audit3" ...`does this help? I think the problem is that I am indexing twice with the `.` once for `~.x ` and once for `~na_if(.` but the second time I am referring to columns. COuld this be the issue?

Comment: Can you check the solution below.  It should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that we are not `get`ting the value of the 'lst' after subsetting

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(mget(lst) ~.x %>%
                  mutate_if(is.character, list(~na_if(.,""))))
```

Comment: Great this works perfectly, only one question: how do I make sure that the output is a series of data frames with the desired changes rather than a list?

Comment: @Alex If you want to return a single dataset, you can use `map_dfr` instead of `map` assuming the column names are the same.  But, if you need to return different objects in the global env, which I don't recommend, use `list2env(map(...), .GlobalEnv)` Depends on what you wanted